# Flutter TextField text not printing to variable?

Tags: dart, textfield, var, flutter

My textfield text for `onChanged:`  I'm trying to change a variable I've declared in the same class and have it print in a voided function.  Please explain how to print my textfield text.

```
class LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override

  var _email;
  var _password;
  var _username;

  final TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();

void _loginButton() {

    print("Login from Page");
    print(_password);
    print(_username);
    print(_email);
  }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        title: new Text("Login / Signup"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new Center(
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new TextField(
                controller: controller,
                decoration:
                new InputDecoration(labelText: "E M A I L   A D D R E S S"),
                onChanged: (String newString){
                  setState((){
                    _email = controller.text;

                  });
                },
              ),
```

Comment: You could call `_loginButton()` either before the `return` in `build` or as the last thing in the `setState` function. But I not sure I really understood your question...

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to complete this with `onChanged:`...

```
new TextField(
                controller: _emailController,
                decoration:
                    new InputDecoration(labelText: "E M A I L   A D D R E S S"),
                onChanged: (str) {
                  setState(() {
                    str = _emailController.text;
                  });
                },
              ),

Future<Null> _loginButton() async {
    try {
      FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();

      print("Login from Page");

      _email = _emailController.text.toString();
      _password = _passController.text.toString();
      _username = _nameController.text.toString();

      print(_email);
      print(_username);
      print(_password);

      await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);

      var userid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;

      if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.photoUrl == null) {
        fb.child("users/${userid}/image").onValue.listen((Event event) {
          print('Child added: ${event.snapshot.value}');
        });
      }

      print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why would you want to log out the user each time they attempt a log in ?

Comment: Also onChanged will return the text being edited by the user, is not onSubmitted better be used here ?

Comment: @aziza I'm calling log out to make sure the FirebaseUser.currentUser is always null before attempting to log another in.   Also,  I think your right about using onSubmitted...  That way I should be able to use a `.whenComplete` call and auto route to my menu.  Is this correct?

Comment: I would suggest adding a sign out button somewhere that clears the user data when clicked and redirect them to the log in screen. And either you use `onSubmitted` to save the user data and navigates to your home, or use a `Button` as in my answer that does the same job when pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure what are you trying to do here. But from what I understand you are trying to save user's input in the `TextField`.

I have achieved this without the need of `setState()`

If you need to obtain the user's input such as email, you should retrieve the data after the user has submitted it, so I am not sure why would you want to use `onChanged` in your case.

Basically what you need to do is to provide the user with a button that should be pressed after they finish filling in the data, and then use your `TextEditingController` to obtain what the user has entered and you can do what you want from there.

This is the code that shows how to do this, I imagine you are trying to do something similar to a Sign Up functionality inside your app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp (),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _email;
  var _password;
  var _username;

  final TextEditingController _nameController = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _emailController = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passController = new TextEditingController();

  void _loginButton({String name, String pass, String email}) {
    print("Login from Page");
    this._username = name;
    this._email = email;
    this._password = pass;
    print(_username);
    print(_email);
    print(_password);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: new Column (
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new TextField(controller: this._nameController, decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: "Type your user name"),),
            new TextField(controller: this._emailController,decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: "Type your email")),
            new TextField(controller: this._passController,decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: "Type your password")),

            new RaisedButton(child: new Text ("Sign In"),
                onPressed: () {
                  _loginButton(name: this._nameController.text,
                      email: this._emailController.text,
                      pass: this._passController.text
                  );
                })
          ],

        ));
  }
}
```

If you do not want to use a button, then use `onSubmitted` property to save user input when the return button is pressed on the keyboard, while `onChanged` will update the value when the `TextField` is being edited.

```
new TextField(controller: this._nameController,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: "Type your user name"),
              onSubmitted: (String s) { //when the user press the return button do this
                _loginButton(name: this._nameController.text);
              },
              onChanged: (String s) { //when the user is editing the text do this
                _loginButton(name: this._nameController.text);
              },),
```

But probably it would be better for you to use a button since you have multiple `TextField` that needs to be saved at once.